# Right aligning looped text in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to right align my printed text with a tab space between the two generated columns.

```py
di = {"name": "John", "Job": "Scientist", "Age": "N/A", "OS": "Mac"}
di = di.items()

for (keys, values) in di:
    print(keys, "\t", values)
```

However I get the below print output.

```
name     John
Job      Scientist
Age      N/A
OS   Mac
```

I have swapped the print statement with `print(f"{keys}{values:>15}")` but it doesn't really help and I get the below print.

```
name           John
Job      Scientist
Age            N/A
OS            Mac
```

I am trying to get this:

```
name     John
Job      Scientist
Age      N/A
OS       Mac
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I would ideally like this to work when printed out in PyCharm or sublime text output when the print command is instructed.

Comment: Note that the input is properly aligned on my terminal. It depends on the tab width. Using a very long key, such as ``firstname`` should trigger the issue reliably.

Answer (score 1):

To specify alignment of printed output utilize the f string formatting capability as indicated in my solution the formatting construct {variable:<} instructs the print to left align the output string.  For more information and a pretty good tutorial see [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and of course the python doc ojn the subject at [Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

```
di = {"name": "John", "Job": "Scientist", "Age": "N/A", "OS": "Mac"}
for key, value in di.items():
    print(f'{key:<}\t{value:<}')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase, I edited my response to add some explanation.

Comment: This works in terminal printout but fails to work in PyCharm printout or sublime text printout. They still have indentation issues.

Comment: Strings are always aligned with themselves. Alignment is meaningless without also setting minimum size of the substitution.